# Is there any plugin for Blog in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, craft-features

I want to create a Blog website in craft cms. I would like to know, is there any plugin for Blog which we can use in Craft similar kind of WordPress?

Comment: There is no plugin like that, but i am working on blog template for Craft CMS. I will have something usable in maybe 2 weeks if you are interested.

Comment: @piotrpog would be great to get in touch for it.

Comment: you can write me on craft slack, my username is Piotr.Pog

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Craft works very differently to WordPress. You won't need a plugin for this, but will need to learn Craft. This looks like it might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfDZ6v23KcE

Answer (score 1):

There is now: https://plugins.craftcms.com/blogify?craft4

See out of the box demo here: https://craftcmsplugins.com/blog/index

Full disclosure, I'm the author.